# Can I roughly estimate thermal expansion by an inverse of the bulk modulus?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, physical-chemistry, estimation

I am browsing the [materials project](https://materialsproject.org/), and want to find which materials expand more when heated. However, expansion coefficients are not given there. There are bulk moduli, and elastic constants calculated with DFT, as well as mass densities.

Can I roughly estimate thermal expansion by an inverse of the bulk modulus? I don't need the exact values, I just want to know if the thermal expansion coefficient of one material is larger when its bulk modulus is smaller. At least, is there such a general trend?

Intuitively, the larger the bulk modulus, the more energy is needed to change the volume. Is my guess correct that $\alpha \sim 1/B~$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good guess: close but not exact! The precise relationship involves the [Grüneisen parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCneisen_parameter)
$$
\gamma\stackrel{def} {=}-\left( \frac{\partial \ln T}{\partial \ln V}\right)_S= \frac{\alpha K_T}{C_V\rho},
$$
where $\alpha$ is the thermal expansion coefficient that you want, $C_V$ is the specific heat per unit volume, $K_T$ is the isothermal bulk modulus that you mention and $\rho$ is the mass density.  The dimensionless number $\gamma$ parameterises the dependence of the frequency of the sound modes on the volume, and is tabulated in various places.

Comment: @ Michael Seifert
  Yes there is a typo!  I left out the logarithms. Will fix.

Comment: Are there some handbooks or databases where $\gamma$ and $C_v$ are given for many materials?